# How to add Simple 3d Bar Graph on top of 2d Feature class in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, graph, chart, 3d-map

I am trying to add a simple bar graph on top of a map in ArcMap. The idea is very simple, to calculate x,y (suppose building area vs building name) and create a bar graph of it. This can easily be done using create graph tool but I want to show a 3D graph(vertical Bars) on top of flat 2D shapefile/feature class. I tried arcScene but this feature is not activated in that. I can create bar graph in 'Symbology' tab but in Arcmap but it won't let me have a 90 degree angle between the graph and feature class.
Is it possible in ESRI Arcmap with or without 3D analyst?

Example of a map I want
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach in ArcScene:

1. Project your map into UTM
2. Use Building foot prints and make extrusion proportionate to Area of the building
3. Categorize the buildings based on their area and color code them.You may want to use   Layer Properties>Symbology>Categories>Select value fields as Area and classify.